# Executing linuxpath without hardcoding the linuxpath in python file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to execute linux path of a file from python script without hardcoding the linux path.

Example:
I have path like 
OUT_PATH = "/home/user/test.yaml"

I want to execute above path like 
os.system("chmod +x **OUT_PATH**")

but not like 
os.system("chmod +x **/home/user/test.yaml**")

if I am executing like first method..it is showing invalid syntax.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The interpreter has no clue that OUT_PATH is to be interpreted as a variable, since it's just a part of the string. Check out Maciek's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 os.system("chmod +x " + OUT_PATH)
```

Comment: If we will use like  OUT_PATH = "/home/user/test.yaml" and IN_PATH = "/home/user/bkp_test.yaml". I want to rename from IN_PATH to OUT_PATH.   How do we write in python using os.system("mv IN_PATH OUT_PATH").  By doing so it is throwing error. so please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
OUT_PATH = "/home/user/test.yaml"
os.system("chmod +x %s" %OUT_PATH)
```